# perl IO::Handle appending file by two scripts at the same time

Tags: perl, file-io

I have two scripts. Which opens a file by

IO::Handle open for appending (">>filename"). then I call $io->autoflush(1);

The question is will it work fine if I do it in two scripts at the same time? Or would some lines be lost while appending?

Comment: It will work if and only if the two program inherit the same shared file descriptor, because the seek pointer is maintained on the single kernel file descriptor that both share. It will not work if the two programs are wholly unrelated to each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That will not work, as append mode is more like shortcut to "open the file, don't truncate it and after opening, seek to the end of file". So yes, you will lose lines.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use [syswrite](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/syswrite.html), like the [Log4Perl docs](http://p3rl.org/Log%3a%3aLog4perl%3a%3aFAQ#How_can_I_synchronize_access_to_an_appender?) suggest for this sort of situation. `syswrite` blocks other writers while writing, and shares the end of file marker with other processes when appending.

Comment: `syswrite` does not block other writers, not even for plain files on a local system on linux. [Demo](https://gist.github.com/904095)

Comment: Well, I feel misinformed ... :-(

Comment: Some OS do small writes atomically, so you might be safe under 4k or something.

Comment: @ikegami: I ran your test with a block size all the way down to 16 bytes (on solaris). And some of the writes were still interrupted :-(